# Why doesn't Python exit from a raised exception when executed with an absolute path?

Tags: python, exception

SOLVED: Rebooting the machine appears to have removed the issue.  I will update if the problem returns.

I'm having an issue where `Python2.6` hangs after an exception is raised, specifically when `foo.py` is called with an absolute path (`/home/user/bar/foo.py`).  I am then required to `ctrl+c` out of the program.  If called from within the `bar` directory as `./foo.py` or from the root directory as `./home/user/bar/foo.py`, the program terminates correctly.

foo.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
print 'begin'
x = [0, 1, undefined]
print 'x'
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
print 'begin'
raise Exception('stopping here')
```

I may also mention that a `sys.exit()` works fine, without issues.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import sys
print 'begin'
sys.exit(0)
```

What is happening to the exception that is failing to terminate the program?  This is likely specific to my configuration.  Where should I begin looking for a solution?

EDIT:  `execfile('/home/user/bar/foo.py')` works fine if running interactive mode.  Additionally, running `nohup /home/user/bar/foo.py &` results in a hanging process that must be killed.

Running CentOS release 6.3 (Final).  This issue did not always exist.  This only started about a month ago over a weekend (I was not using the machine at that time).

UPDATE: Debugging with GDB, the backtrace points to `libpthread.so.0`.

```
#0  0x000000364340e890 in __connect_nocancel () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff18960d8 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so
#2  0x00007ffff189815c in ?? () from /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so
#3  0x00007ffff7d0a706 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#4  0x00007ffff7d0c797 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#5  0x00007ffff7d0abe4 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#6  0x00007ffff7d0bccf in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#7  0x00007ffff7d0bccf in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#8  0x00007ffff7d0c797 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#9  0x00007ffff7c9adb0 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#10 0x00007ffff7c70303 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#11 0x00007ffff7d04dd3 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#12 0x00007ffff7d28cd2 in PyErr_PrintEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#13 0x00007ffff7d29297 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#14 0x00007ffff7d35c32 in Py_Main () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#15 0x000000364281ecdd in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#16 0x0000000000400649 in _start ()
```

Anybody know what this means?

Comment: Have you tested this with any other versions of Python to see if the issue is limited to 2.6? It would help in being able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Also I just tested this on Python 2.4.3, 2.6.5, and 2.7.3 and was unable to get the program to hang. Something else on your system (configuration setting or something) must be contributing somehow.

Comment: I do not have sudo privileges on this machine to try another version.

Comment: Tested on Python 2.4.3/RHEL 5.5, no repro

Comment: @user1742131 hm, how is it that you need sudo privileges to run another version of Python?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Most probably he is talking about doing a system wide install of a new Python version.

Comment: Correct, I cannot install another python version.  Also execfile() works fine with an absolute path.

Comment: Do you have a box which is similarly configured? Are you able to reproduce this issue on some other box?

Comment: @Sanjay ah, the wording implied there was another Python version already installed which could not be run without `sudo` access. (Of course one _can_ always compile Python and try to run it directly from the build directory, but probably not worth the trouble for this)

Comment: the issue might be that the process is suspended when it tries to print something to stderr. You could test it with a bash script: `echo test >&2` Check your terminal settings (try: `stty sane`, `reset`)

Comment: What sort of machine is this running on?  It seems to be quite specific to this machine.  Is this a 'standard' build (ie - the distro version) of Python or was it built in-house?  Are you sure you're actually running the python interpreter or is there a wrapper script involved?  Do you have anything weird going on in your system's site.py?

Comment: The bash script works fine. `stty sane` doesn't help.

Comment: Running CentOS.  The problem didn't exist before.  Something happened at some point to something.  The python version hasn't changed.  Problem exists if I run it from a bash script, run with `nohup`, run by specifying `/path/foo.py` in the terminal, or run by calling `python /path/foo.py`.

Comment: does `print("abc")` as the only line in the Python script work?  If you set `sys.excepthook` to write to a file (flush it on every write); do you see any tracebacks in the file?

Comment: `print("abc")` works fine.  I don't understand what you mean with the `sys.excepthook`.  Care to explain with detail?  (I've added debug info up top btw.)

Comment: What's really odd is your gdb traceback shows Python down in the socket module - but your example code does not show any use of the socket module. Any ideas about your code that could shed light on that?

Comment: Another user ran the debugger.  He may have used different code.  More than one of us is trying to fix the issue.

Comment: Looking at the stack more closely, it looks like the exception fires and then Python starts running some code to print out the exception that then leads it down into the socket module where it never returns. It's not clear why printing an exception would lead into the socket module. Can you produce a stack trace that matches your example script?

Comment: I ran gdb myself and got essentially the same thing. (The OP now shows my own debug traceback.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reboot the machine.

Bowing to the graces of the all-powerful admin, I was able to get the machine rebooted.  All is well.  I'll update the question if the problem returns.

Answer (score 1):

This exact issue has been biting me for awhile now on a RHEL 6 machine.  In certain cases, Exceptions cause a hang.  In fact, I was able to take your code verbatim and reproduce the symptom.

Thanks to the abrtd answer, I determined that abrt-addon-python package was installed which puts abrt_exception_handler.py into the site-packages location, and that is called during python startup.  This file overrides the sys.excepthook function which contacts the abrt daemon using sockets.  See [ABRT Project Doc](http://abrt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/design.html) for more information.

I verified that adding -S to the python invocation prevents the hang.  This is not a good solution, however, because the -S option prevents ALL site packages from being imported on startup.

A better solution is to add the following in your python code:

```
import sys
sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
```

which restores the original exception hook and prevents the hang.

Answer (score 0):

- please inspect `sys.path` for non absolute directories.
- you can always [break into it with a debugger, e.g. gdb](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb)
- sometimes I have stuff in `PYTHONSTARTUP`, which causes the interactive interpreter to do something different...
- `strace` can aslo be your friend

Answer (score 0):

I tracked this problem down. It is trying to write to a socket that was held open by abrtd.

Restarting abrtd 'fixed' the issue. This is why the machine reboot worked. I haven't found the root cause of the issue though.