# Python won't exit when called with absolute path from cron or subshell

Tags: python, relative-path, freeze, absolute-path, unhandled-exception

I have some python scripts that run via cron, and they no longer exit correctly when the script is called with an absolute path.  They will hang until the process is terminated.  I believe it happened after I moved /var and /home to a different partition.

I checked into the environment variables and couldn't see anything obviously wrong, this happens either when run with cron or a bash subshell, but not when run directly.

If I run it as a subshell it hangs until I kill it (ctrl-c) and then gives me the output.

```
[wotstats@rock test]$ echo 'assert 0==1, "fails"' > test.py
[wotstats@rock test]$ /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/python /var/home/wotstats/test/test.py"
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/home/wotstats/test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    assert 0==1, "fails"
AssertionError: fails
```

If I don't call a script it terminates as expected without hanging:

```
[wotstats@rock test]$ /bin/bash -c "echo 'assert 0==1, \"fails\"' | /usr/bin/python"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: fails
```

I do get an immediate log error when the exception occurs:

```
Dec  9 13:33:44 rock abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in '/var/home/wotstats/test/test.py'
```

I ran some tests based on the input, and found that this problem occurs even when called as /test.py and when run as root.  I also tried /root and /usr with the same effect.

[Similar or same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865637/why-doesnt-python-exit-from-a-raised-exception-when-executed-with-an-absolute-p) was asked here and resolved by reboot; I'd rather figure it out and avoid the reboot if I can.

Comment: Maybe this is a bash thing rather than a python thing? Try substituting another shell.

Comment: sh/csh/tcsh have the same behavior.

Comment: Ran a php script and it died immediately.

Comment: OK, so not that. It's hard to imagine what moving /var and home could have to do with it.

Comment: Does the path have anything to do with it? What if your /usr/bin/python argument is simply test.py instead of the full path?

Comment: That could be a red herring, but the only change I can think of.  This has been in place for awhile, so whatever broke it was done months ago.  I did have problems with SELinux, but put that into permissive mode and it still has the same behavior.

Comment: Try another path as suggested above.

Comment: Ok, it is a path thing.  Calling it with just the script name works.  Any ideas?  I'm not sure how to test this.

Comment: Good! This is progress. I don't know either but now you should edit the question so someone with expertise will notice it.

Comment: Along the lines of tracking it down, I suggest trying to determine which path component triggers it by moving the file up the hierarchy. Then try to find out what is different about that folder.

Comment: Updated while not logged in, so the edits are in queue.  However it fails even as /test.py and in other directories.  Ran it as root also to confirm it wasn't a user permissions issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, got it figured out.  Thanks for the help.

I ran an strace and found that it was hanging on the following:

```
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/abrt/abrt.socket"}, 27^C
<unfinished ...>
```

That led to [Bugzilla](https://partner-bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=614752) which indicated that SELinux was the problem.  I had already changed SELinux to permissive mode (I screwed it up moving /var), but had not restarted abrtd.

Restarting the `abrtd` service resolved the problem.

Comment: Good debugging there. I always forget about strace.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
/usr/bin/python /var/home/wotstats/test/test.py
```

use:

```
cd /var/home/wotstats/test/
/usr/bin/python test.py<br/>
```