# Python scripts hang on exception until ctrl-c

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

I have an issue with running python scripts on one server running RH Linux with Python 2.6.6.  When I run any script and it produces an exception, the script hangs until I press CTRL-C and then it prints the traceback information.  It happens when I run the script from the command-line without calling python directly, making use of the shebang on the first line of the script.  If I execute the script by calling python , I don't have the same hanging issue.  I've searched and seen similar issues, but they were related to specific libraries where this happens with all python scripts.  I've tried a different servers with the same script and didn't have the issue.  I have included a simple script that I have been testing with.  It tries to open a non-existent file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
tempfile = open('noexists.txt','r')
```

When I execute the code as "test.py" on the command-line, I get the following response:

```
~/bin$> test.py
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/export/home/jwd3/bin/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    tempfile = open('noexists.txt','r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'noexists.txt'
```

If I execute it as "python test.py" then I get the following response:

```
~/bin$> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    tempfile = open('noexists.txt','r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'noexists.txt'
```

The difference is difficult to tell here, but it is very evident when executing.  Look at the first sample output and notice the "^C" before the Traceback.  Until I hit CTRL-C, the script was just hanging.  The second sample output returns the traceback of the exception imediately without hanging.

I've tried moving the script to a new location, changing the shebang from #!/usr/bin/python to #!/usr/bin/env python and different scripts.  In all cases they behave the same.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I do not want to call all python scripts using "python " format.

Comment: What output do you get if you run "which python" on the command line?

Comment: What do you have if you just run python from the command line and then insert you command "tempfile = open('noexists.txt','r')"?

Can you give us your python version?

Can you list (using ll) your current directory (from where you run your script)?

Comment: @RobWatts /usr/bin/python

Comment: @hzrari  Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May  1 2012, 13:52:17)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> tempfile = open('noexists.txt','r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'noexists.txt'
>>>

Comment: have tried using strace to see what's blocking the process?

Comment: After using strace, I found it was hanging on a socket call.  A quick search on Google found a similar issue already posted on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790475/python-wont-exit-when-called-with-absolute-path-from-cron-or-subshell).  Restarting the abrtd service fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from the suggestions above, I was able to find the solution to the issue.  After running strace, I found the code was hanging on a socket connection.  Searching for the same socket connection info, I found another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790475/python-wont-exit-when-called-with-absolute-path-from-cron-or-subshell) already posted on Stack Overflow that was similar.  I then found a second [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865637/why-doesnt-python-exit-from-a-raised-exception-when-executed-with-an-absolute-p?rq=1) that was also very similar.  Both issues had the same suggestion.  Apparently the Python script was conflicting with a service called abrtd.  The suggestion was to restart this service (abrtd).  After restarting it, the issue with the Python script hanging was resolved.